# How do I create a contingency table of overlapping categories?

Tags: r, contingency

I have this dataframe:

`` structure(list(`Product Name` = c("Apple", "Banana", "Cherry", "Date", "Elderberry", "Fig", "Guava", "Honeydew", "Kiwi", "Lemon"), Benefits_Claim = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE), Warnings_Claim = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), Instructions_Claim = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), Features_Claim = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")) ``

I want to create a contingency table that shows counts of overlapping values ... I'm not sure if that's the best way to put it, but ideally it should look something like this:

| (blank) | Benefits | Warnings | Instructions | Features |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Benefits |  |  |  |  |
| Warnings |  |  |  |  |
| Instructions |  |  |  |  |
| Features |  |  |  |  |

And the cell overlap of warnings and benefits should show the count of fruits that have both a Benefit and Warning value as TRUE, and so on.

I don't have much code to show for this as I don't really understand how to approach -- any advice gratefully received.

Comment: please show the actual desired output, rather than just the structure. The example output should include cell values. As is, the question is hard to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the matrix crossproduct of your table:

```
crossprod(as.matrix(df[-1]))

                   Benefits_Claim Warnings_Claim Instructions_Claim Features_Claim
Benefits_Claim                  3              2                  2              3
Warnings_Claim                  2              9                  8              3
Instructions_Claim              2              8                  8              3
Features_Claim                  3              3                  3              4
```

Cleaned up and diagonal set to zero:

```
df|>
  setNames(sub("_Claim$", "", names(df))) |>
  subset(select = -`Product Name`) |>
  as.matrix() |>
  crossprod() |> 
  `diag<-`(0)

             Benefits Warnings Instructions Features
Benefits            0        2            2        3
Warnings            2        0            8        3
Instructions        2        8            0        3
Features            3        3            3        0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do this using base R -

```
sapply(df[-1], \(x) sapply(df[-1], \(y) sum(x & y)))

#                   Benefits_Claim Warnings_Claim Instructions_Claim Features_Claim
#Benefits_Claim                  3              2                  2              3
#Warnings_Claim                  2              9                  8              3
#Instructions_Claim              2              8                  8              3
#Features_Claim                  3              3                  3              4
```